# Py visa suddenly won't start ctypes 'module' object has no attribute 'c_ulong'

Tags: python, ctypes, pyvisa

I don't understand how this happened. Friday my code was working perfectly fine! Then today I couldn't import visa any longer. I uninstalled python x,y and deleted the python27 folder then re-installed python x,y and reinstalled pyvisa 1.4 (version I had been using previously) and still getting the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/matthew/PycharmProjects/untitled8/Automated_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import visa
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\visa.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyvisa.visa import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import vpp43
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\vpp43.py", line 49, in <module>
    from vpp43_types import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvisa\vpp43_types.py", line 63, in <module>
    ViUInt32, ViPUInt32, ViAUInt32    = _type_triplet(_ctypes.c_ulong)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'c_ulong'
```

Comment: Did you call one of your own files `ctypes.py`?

Comment: Actually I think the problem is with pycharm. I created a new project and loaded up python and import visa is working again.